# How to use same route path for both locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this code in routes.rb.

```
scope ":locale", :locale => /es/  do
    match "inicio" => "home#index", :as => "home"
    match "acerca-de" => "about#index", :as => "about"
    match "servicios" => "services#index", :as => "services"
    match "blog" => "blog#index", :as => "blog"
    match "contacto" => "contact#index", :as => "contact"
  end

  scope ":locale", :locale => /en/  do
    match "home" => "home#index", :as => "home"
    match "about" => "about#index", :as => "about"
    match "services" => "services#index", :as => "services"
    match "blog" => "blog#index", :as => "blog"
    match "contact" => "contact#index", :as => "contact"
  end
```

What I'm trying to do is have a route like `/es/acerca-de` and `/en/about` which use the same controller and have the same `url_path()` so when I'm at spanish language the `about_path()` sends you to `/en/about` but when I'm at english language the `about_path()` sends you to `/es/acerca-de`.

Answer (score 1):

Done!
I the answer was practically in the ruby on rails guides...

This is the code in routes.rb

```
scope ":locale", :locale => /es|en/  do
 match "inicio" => "home#index", :as => "home"
 match "acerca-de" => "about#index", :as => "about"
 match "servicios" => "services#index", :as => "services"
 match "blog" => "blog#index", :as => "blog"
 match "contacto" => "contact#index", :as => "contact"
end
```

and added this in application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 def set_locale
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
   Saba::Application.reload_routes!
 end
```